# Apply the Euclidean algorithm to $2$ and $1 − 3i$ in the integers of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt {-1}]$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, field-theory

*Question:*

I have to apply the Euclidean algorithm to $2$ and $1 − 3i$ in the integers of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt {-1}]$

*My Solution:*

Since $N(2) = 4$ and $N(1–3i) = 10,$ we must start by dividing $1–3i$ by 2, getting  $\frac12 - \frac32i$. We now want the closest Gaussian integer to that quotient. There are four possible choices here, and it doesn't matter which one we take: the real part could be 0 or 1, and the imaginary part could be $–i$ or $–2i.$ Let's take $–i$ as the Gaussian integer closest to the quotient. Then the first step in the Euclidean algorithm will look like this:

$1-3i = 2(-i) + (1-i) ... $ (where $–i$ is the Gaussian quotient, $1–i$ is the remainder).

For the next step of the algorithm, we must divide 2 by $1–i.$ But this time the quotient is a Gaussian integer, because $2 = (1–i)(1+i).$ So the remainder is $0,$ and the $\gcd{(2, 1–3)}$ is the last nonzero remainder, namely $1–i.$

Is this correct? What can I add to it?

Comment: Looks right to me. You can check that $1-i$ is a factor of both $2$ and $1-3i$. You've already checked $2$.