# Prove by counterexample that $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are not necessarily unique

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

Assume $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{d}]$ is a Euclidean Field and  $\alpha$,  $\beta$ are two quadratic integers in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{d}]$, so that there exists integers  $\gamma$ and  $\delta$ in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{d}]$ so that $\alpha = \gamma \beta + \delta$, and  $|N(\delta)|<|N(\beta)|$. How can we prove by counterexample that  $\gamma$ and  $\delta$ are not necessarily unique?

Comment: $d=-1$, $\alpha=2+i$, $\beta=1+i$ with $\gamma=1,\delta=1$ or $\gamma=2,\delta=-i$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Can you show how you arrived to this?

Comment: @Rachel: One way that one might arrive at this example is from looking at the standard proof that in the Gaussian integers such a $\gamma$, $\delta$ exist. The usual proof considers the number $\theta=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=x+iy$ where $x$ and $y$ are rational. Then if $p$ and $q$ respectively are the nearest integers to $x$ and $y$, one shows that choosing $\gamma=p+iq$ works. In the counterexample, there are two nearest integers to $x$ and $y$, since $x$ and $y$ are each half of an odd integer. That gives $4$ choices for the ordered pair $(p,q)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas In this case p and q being  $\lambda$ and δ

Comment: Here $\gamma=p+iq$, so $\delta$ is defined as $\alpha-(p+iq)\beta$.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question when you asked this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264678/apply-the-euclidean-algorithm-to-2-and-1-%E2%88%92-3i-in-the-integers-of-mathbb-q.

Comment: @EthanBolker What do you mean?

Comment: What follows from your correct assertion there that there are "four possible choices"?

Answer (score 0):

Let $d=-1$, so that our field is $\mathbb Q[i]$ and the ring of integers is $\mathbb Z[i]$. Then for fixed $\beta$, the numbers $\gamma\beta$ with $\gamma\in\mathbb Z[i]$ form a square lattice. The trick is now to translate this lattice in such a manner that it has two distinct points of minimal norm. So for example we can let $\beta=2$ and translate it by $1+i$ (so that $0$ now is in the middle of a square "mesh" of the lattice). Then the translated lattice points $\pm1\pm i\in(1+i)+2\mathbb Z[i]$ all have norm $N(\pm 1\pm i)=1^2+1^2=2<4=N(2)$. Thus with arbitray $\alpha \in (1+i)+2\mathbb Z[i]$ we will obtain a counterexample as desired, for example

$$\alpha=1+i,\  \beta=2, \ \begin{cases}\gamma=0,&\delta=1+i\\\gamma=1,&\delta=-1+i\\\gamma=i,&\delta=1-i\\\gamma=1+i,&\delta=-1-i\end{cases} $$
This even gives us a "four-fold" counterexample.

Comment: I haven't learned what a lattice is. Is there another way to show this?